# How to switch text in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to switch text but I always fail.

Let's say I want to switch,

`I` with `We` in`x='I are We'`
I tried

```
x=x.replace('I','We').replace('We','I')
```

but it is obvious that it will print `I are I`

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with function as a substitution:

```
In [9]: import re

In [10]: x = 'I are We'

In [11]: re.sub('I|We', lambda match: 'We' if match.group(0) == 'I' else 'I', x)
Out[11]: 'We are I'
```

If you need to replace more than 2 substrings you may want to create a dict like `d = {'I': 'We', 'We': 'I', 'You': 'Not You'}` and pick correct replacement like `lambda match: d[match.group(0)]`. You may also want to construct regular expression dynamically based on the replacement strings, but make sure to escape them:

```
In [14]: d = {'We': 'I', 'I': 'We', 'ar|e': 'am'}

In [15]: re.sub('|'.join(map(re.escape, d.keys())), lambda match: d[match.group(0)], 'We ar|e I')
Out[15]: 'I am We'
```

Comment: Oh, same answer at the same time :)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted 

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to avoid going through your string several times (Each replace go through the list) and to make it more readable ! It also works on several occurences words.

```
string = 'I are We, I'

import re

replacements = {'I': 'We', 'We': 'I'}
print(re.sub("I|We", lambda x: replacements[x.group()], string)) # Matching words you want to replace, and replace them using a dict
```

## Output

```
"We are I, We"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit clunky, but i tend to do something along the lines of

```
x='I are We'
x=x.replace('I','we')
x=x.replace('We','I')
x=x.replace('we','We')
```

Which can be shortened to

`x=x.replace('I','we').replace('We','I').replace('we','We')

Answer (score 1):

```
x='I are We'
x=x.replace('I','You').replace('We','I').replace('You','We')
>>> x
'We are I'
```

Comment: Worth mention that this will replace all `You` substrings in the source string as well.

Comment: Its just to demonstrate a technique :)

Comment: Actually my code is very long. It is a bit problematic to use this. Looking for a simpler solution.....

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make use of `replace`, but I hope it helps:

```
s = "I are We"
d = {"I": "We", "We": "I"}

" ".join([d.get(x, x) for x in s.split()])

>>> 'We are I'
```

Comment: Op gave just a simple example, does not work if it gets any punctuation, e.g. `We, are I` won't give `I, are we` as I think the OP wants

Answer (score 0):

```
x='I are We'
dic = {'I':'We','We':'I'}
sol = []
for i in x.split():
    if i in dic:
        sol.append(dic[i])
    else:
        sol.append(i)

result = ' '.join(sol)
print(result)
```

Comment: Op gave just a simple example, does not work if it gets any punctuation, e.g. `We, are I` won't give `I, are we` as I think the OP wants